# Can I specify that I don't want to start the application when I push it in the manifest.yml file?

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

When I push my application using the cf cli I can specify that I don't want to start the app using the `--no-start` flag, is the same feature not available for the manifest.yml? If not, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting instances field to 0 , see details at http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#instances

Comment: nice idea but instances need to be > 0 or it will throw an error: `FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100001, message: The app is invalid: Number of instances less than 1`